# Save image picked from ReactNative/Expo ImagePicker to Baqend

Tags: baqend

I'm having a hard time saving an image that is being picked from Expo (React Native).

https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/imagepicker.html

It seems that React Native does not have support for uploading the selected image as blob, but does have a base64 option.

The code:

```
_pickImage = async () => {
    let pickerResult = await ImagePicker.launchImageLibraryAsync({
        allowsEditing: true,
        base64: true,
        aspect: [4, 4],
    });
    this._handleImagePicked(pickerResult);
};


_handleImagePicked(pickerResult) {
    const uri = pickerResult.base64;
    const img = new db.File({ name: 'test.jpg', data: uri, type: 'base64', mimeType: 'image/jpg' });

    db.UserData.load(this.state.UserDataID).then(UserData => {
        img.upload({ force: true }).then((file) => {
            UserData.photo = "https://remarkable-apple-95.app.baqend.com/v1" + file.id;
            alert(file.id)
            return UserData.update();
        },
            (error) => { alert(error); }
        );
    });
}
```

When I `console.log(pickerResult.base64)` I get a super long string that looks like base64, but when this is run, the `img.upload` is throwing the error and it says `"PersistentError: An unexpected persistent error occurred."`

Answer (score 1):

You're right. React Native has no support for binary data. Unfortunately Baqend does not support base64 file uploads yet.

As a workaround you have 2 options:

1. Use the [React Native Fetch Blob](https://github.com/wkh237/react-native-fetch-blob) library, which bypasses the limitations of React Native not supporting binary files by uploading and downloading the files directly via native code and gives back a reference to those. Your code could look similar to this:

   ```
   ImagePicker.showImagePicker(options, async (response) => {
       const upload = new db.message.UploadFile('files', 'uploadFetchBlob.jpg')
       const body = 'RNFetchBlob-' + response.uri;
       RNFetchBlob.fetch('PUT', 'https://{YOUR-APP-NAME}.app.baqend.com/v1' + upload.request.path, upload.request.headers, body).then((res) => {
           db.File({ parent: 'files', name: 'uploadFetchBlob.jpg'}).url
       })
   });
   ```

Unfortunately this wont work with the expo client right now, but you'd have to eject your project and use 'native code'.

2. The second option would be not to use the baqend file endpoint directly, but upload your base64 string to a baqend module instead. There you can parse your base64 string and upload it to your files from within your backend module. You can find an example for this in our Guide. https://www.baqend.com/guide/topics/baqend-code/#handling-binary-data

Hope this helps